# php mailer not picking up date picker or select time

Tags: php, forms, select, datepicker, phpmailer

Hi there just working on a contact form for a mate.He wants to be able for people to request a time and date. I have used the php mailer and it works when using the input type-text but when i add in (jQuery)date picker and time (select)it doesn't send the email.Any help would be appreciated.

I have added in the last bit of my html form below and php mailer code.
used the name="rtime" for time select and name="rdate"for date picker.

FORM CODE BELOW _ _ _

```
                <select name="rtime" id="">

                    <option value="" name="9am">9:00am</option>
                    <option value="" name="10am">10:00am</option>
                    <option value="" name="11am">11:00am</option>
                    <option value="" name="12pm">12:00pm</option>
                    <option value="" name="1pm">1:00pm</option>
                    <option value="" name="2pm">2:00pm</option>
                    <option value="" name="3pm">3:00pm</option>
                    <option value="" name="4pm">4:00pm</option>

                </select>

               <input type="text"  id="datepicker" placeholder="Reqested Date" class="block col-10 mb2 field" name="rdate">
```

PHP MAILER CODE - - - -

require './PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if(isset($_POST["name"])){

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$fromEmail = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$rTime = $_POST["rtime"];
$rDate = $_POST["rdate"];


//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom($fromEmail, 'Whitersmile Website Enquiry');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo($fromEmail, $name);
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('info@whitersmile.co.nz', 'Whitersmile Website Enquiry');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = $name . ' has enquired on the website';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML("Name:  ".$name."<br> Phone:  ".$phone ."<br> Email:  " .$fromEmail."<br> Requested time:  ".$rTime."<br> Requested date:  ".$rDate.
```

"
 Message:  ".$message);
    //Replace the plain text body with one created manually

```
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
   header("Location:../index.php#formWrapperContact");
} else {
   header("Location:../index.php?message=Thank+You#thankyouMessage");
}
   //header("");
}
```

Comment: In your options you want value="9am" not name="9am"

Comment: Thanks Heaps Matt !!